# Android 8 Foreground Service with Notification Channel

Tags: android, service, foreground-service, notification-channel

I want to start a foreground service in Android 8 and I want to know how are foreground services compatible with the notification channel system.

Let's say we start a foreground service, then we immediately create the required notification and assign it to a notification channel. Suddenly, the user decides to go into System Settings and disable the notification channel.

What happens in this case? Will the service become a background service? Does it get killed? I haven't found a documented answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default notification settings:

[image]

Foreground service notification:
[image]

Disable notifications:

[image]

Android 8 shows this notification after few seconds (when you send your application to background):

[image]